# Get related_name of Django ForeignKey field at runtime

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='pets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to get the string value of `related_name` for `Pet.person` at runtime. I can get the `related_query_name`, which is `"pet"` but that's slightly different than the `related_name`, which is `"pets"`:

```
print(Pet._meta.get_field("person").related_query_name())
# pet
```

Looks like the related name is on the `Person` class, but I'm not sure how to prove it's tied to `Pet.person`.

```
print("pets" in [f.name for f in Person._meta.get_fields()])
# True
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Are u want to show Person and their pets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
related_name = Pet._meta.get_field('person').remote_field.get_accessor_name()

related_query_name = Pet._meta.get_field('person').related_query_name()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when `related_name` is not set. It returns `None` but I want it to return `pet_set` which would become the default. I can get that by replacing `.related_name` with `.get_accessor_name()`